# Как получить координаты обектов в канвасе?

Tags: html, jquery, canvas, веб-программирование, fabricjs

Подскажите, как узнать координаты обектов в канвасе?

Comment: Без библиотеки, такого понятия (т.е. объекты в канвасе) нету.

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию (в обычных рамках HTML+JavaScript) в Canvas не существует объектов. Это просто холст, на котором просто рисуются пиксели, которые после прорисовки становятся неотъемлемой частью холста.

С помощью [fabricjs](/questions/tagged/fabricjs) можно добавить уровень объектов к Canvas-у, манипулировать ими, двигать, масштабировать, поворачивать, перекрашивать, менять z-index и т.п.

[Вот русскоязычный официальный учебник для самых начинающих](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1_ru/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]